# Summing 2 to the power of the subset sums of a power set

Tags: exponentiation, summation

Sorry in advance, as I suspect I lack both the proper terms and the proper notation for the problem I have, but I'll try to be clear.

If I have a set $S = \{1,2,3\}$, I figured out that the summation of the "subset sums" of its power set is $\sum_i S_i \times 2^{|S| - 1}$.

For instance, as $P(S) = \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$, this sum is $0+1+2+3+3+4+5+6=24$, i.e. $6 \times 2^2$.

Now I'd like to find a formula for the related summation where instead of summing the "subset sums", I sum 2 to their power: $2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6=135$.

I tried to reverse-engineer this formula for a long time, using many examples, but it completely eludes me.. Thanks for any help or clarification!

Comment: Your formula for the sum is correct.  The simple justification is that there are $2^{|S|}$ subsets and each element is in half of them, so the element contributes $2^{|S|-1}$ times to the sum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Denoting your summation with $f(S)$, we have the follwoing facts:
$$f(\emptyset)=1$$
and if $S':=S\setminus\{x\}$ for some $x\in S$, then 
$$ f(S) = f(S')\cdot(1+2^x)$$
because the subsets of $S$ can be partitioned into those not containing $x$ (giving $f(S')$) and those containing $x$ (where each sorresponding summand is multiplied by $2^x$).
Therefore, one readily sees that 
$$f(S)=\prod_{x\in S}(1+2^x).$$
In your example: $(1+2^1)(1+2^2)(1+2^3)=3\cdot 5\cdot 9=135$.

Comment: Many thanks! I am puzzled and greatly impressed by your speed.. is that a reasoning that you made on the fly, or you had somehow thought about a related problem before?

Comment: Hm, both I guess.